# How to create plot with multiple entries

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the following dataset

```
p   start   end     Per     pm  on  IOI rat id
1   106.0   107.3   133.3   3.1 6   0.4 3.1 2
1   106.1   107.3   133.3   3.1 6   0.1 1.0 3
1   106.3   107.3   133.3   3.1 6   0.2 1.7 4
1   106.6   107.3   133.3   3.1 6   0.3 2.2 5
1   107.1   107.3   133.3   3.1 6   0.5 3.8 6
2   107.8   109.4   162.0   8.7 6   0.2 1.0 2
2   108.0   109.4   162.0   8.7 6   0.1 0.9 3
2   108.1   109.4   162.0   8.7 6   0.2 0.9 4
2   108.3   109.4   162.0   8.7 6   0.2 1.1 5
2   108.5   109.4   162.0   8.7 6   0.2 1.0 6
3   111.2   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 1.0 2
3   111.4   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 0.9 3
3   111.5   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 1.0 4
3   111.7   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 1.0 5
3   111.9   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 1.0 6
3   112.3   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.4 2.0 7
3   112.4   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 1.0 8
4   112.7   113.6   172.8   7.6     6   0.1 0.8 2
4   112.9   113.6   172.8   7.6     6   0.2 0.9 3
4   113.0   113.6   172.8   7.6     6   0.1 0.8 4
4   113.2   113.6   172.8   7.6     6   0.2 1.0 5
4   113.4   113.6   172.8   7.6      6  0.2 1.1 6
5   115.5   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 1.0 2
5   115.6   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 0.9 3
5   115.8   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 0.9 4
5   116.0   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 1.0 5
5   116.2   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 1.0 6
5   116.6   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.4 2.0 7
5   116.8   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 1.0 8
6   117.1   118.2   160.0   8.9     6   0.2 1.0 2
6   117.2   118.2   160.0   8.9     6   0.1 0.9 3
6   117.4   118.2   160.0   8.9     6   0.1 0.9 4
6   117.5   118.2   160.0   8.9     6   0.2 1.0 5
6   117.7   118.2   160.0   8.9     6   0.2 1.1 6
7   121.8   123.6   125.0   5.4     8   0.2 1.2 2
7   122.1   123.6   125.0   5.4     8   0.4 2.9 3
7   122.3   123.6   125.0   5.4     8   0.1 1.0 4
7   122.5   123.6   125.0   5.4     8   0.3 2.2 5
```

And I would like to create one scattered plot with multiple entries based on subsets from this df. x = `id` and y = `rat`. The subsets are determined by the column `p`, so I would create one plot with entries (`id`, `rat`) from phrases 2,4,7 aligned and displayed in different colours.

I've started by making subsets with the `filter` function

```
phrase2 <- dt %>%
  filter(dt$p == 2)

phrase4 <- dt %>%
  filter(dt$p == 4)

phrase7 <- dt %>%
  filter(dt$p == 7)
```

But I couldn't figure out how to create the plots and be able to control the colours of each subset (this becomes difficult if I combine them into one new dt, for instance)

Comment: Which plot are you thinking of?

Comment: In ggplot, it is much easier to control the colors of each subset if they are in one data frame--it's a little confusing that you state the opposite. For example, `dt_new <- dt %>% filter(phrase %in% c(2, 4, 7))`, then `ggplot(dt_new, aes(color = factor(phrase), ...) + ... + scale_color_manual(values = c("firebrick3", "chartreuse", "orange")` Not sure what kind of plot you want so it's hard to show more code than that.

Comment: As a side note, don't use `$` inside `dplyr` functions like `filter`. Using `$` will ignore any `group_by` and break code, so it is a bad habit and should be avoided even in cases like this where it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention, I'm looking for a scattered plot.

Comment: @GregorThomas, you code would look something like this?

`dt_new <- dt %>% filter(phrase %in% c(2, 4, 7)`
  `ggplot(dt_new, aes(id, rat, color = factor(phrase) +                 scale_color_manual(values = c("firebrick3", "chartreuse", "orange")`

Comment: Yes, something like that. If you want a scatter plot then you also need `+ geom_point()`

Comment: @GregorThomas, I'm trying to run `ggplot(dt_new, aes(color = factor(phrase)+geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values = c("firebrick3", "chartreuse", "orange")` but it is not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think there's confusion because your sample data doesn't have a `phrase` column (maybe you mean the `p` column?). And yes, you're missing several `)`.

Comment: Oh sorry, indeed I meant the `p` column - I had to adapt from my dataset and forgot to change this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dt_new <- dt %>% filter(p %in% c(2, 4, 7))

ggplot(dt_new, aes(id, rat, color = factor(p))) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("firebrick3", "chartreuse", "orange"))
```

[image]

Using this data:

```
dt = read.table(text = 'p   start   end     Per     pm  on  IOI rat id
1   106.0   107.3   133.3   3.1 6   0.4 3.1 2
1   106.1   107.3   133.3   3.1 6   0.1 1.0 3
1   106.3   107.3   133.3   3.1 6   0.2 1.7 4
1   106.6   107.3   133.3   3.1 6   0.3 2.2 5
1   107.1   107.3   133.3   3.1 6   0.5 3.8 6
2   107.8   109.4   162.0   8.7 6   0.2 1.0 2
2   108.0   109.4   162.0   8.7 6   0.1 0.9 3
2   108.1   109.4   162.0   8.7 6   0.2 0.9 4
2   108.3   109.4   162.0   8.7 6   0.2 1.1 5
2   108.5   109.4   162.0   8.7 6   0.2 1.0 6
3   111.2   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 1.0 2
3   111.4   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 0.9 3
3   111.5   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 1.0 4
3   111.7   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 1.0 5
3   111.9   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 1.0 6
3   112.3   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.4 2.0 7
3   112.4   112.5   180.0   10.6    8   0.2 1.0 8
4   112.7   113.6   172.8   7.6     6   0.1 0.8 2
4   112.9   113.6   172.8   7.6     6   0.2 0.9 3
4   113.0   113.6   172.8   7.6     6   0.1 0.8 4
4   113.2   113.6   172.8   7.6     6   0.2 1.0 5
4   113.4   113.6   172.8   7.6      6  0.2 1.1 6
5   115.5   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 1.0 2
5   115.6   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 0.9 3
5   115.8   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 0.9 4
5   116.0   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 1.0 5
5   116.2   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 1.0 6
5   116.6   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.4 2.0 7
5   116.8   116.8   187.5   9.2     8   0.2 1.0 8
6   117.1   118.2   160.0   8.9     6   0.2 1.0 2
6   117.2   118.2   160.0   8.9     6   0.1 0.9 3
6   117.4   118.2   160.0   8.9     6   0.1 0.9 4
6   117.5   118.2   160.0   8.9     6   0.2 1.0 5
6   117.7   118.2   160.0   8.9     6   0.2 1.1 6
7   121.8   123.6   125.0   5.4     8   0.2 1.2 2
7   122.1   123.6   125.0   5.4     8   0.4 2.9 3
7   122.3   123.6   125.0   5.4     8   0.1 1.0 4
7   122.5   123.6   125.0   5.4     8   0.3 2.2 5', header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in base R, you could try the following.

```
# Read in sample data as `df`

# Subset data 
plotdata <- df[df$p %in% c(2,4,7),]

#Create scatter plot
with(plotdata, plot(x = id, y = rat, col = p, pch = 20, bty = "n"))
legend("topleft", as.character(unique(plotdata$p)), col = unique(plotdata$p),
       pch = 20, bty = "n", title = "p")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this, it worked. One quick question - if I want to have lines instead of dots, should I replace the "pch = 20" for another value or add a different command?

Comment: No if you want a line, add `type = "l"` to the `plot()` command